# Show facebook , twitter and other installed apps in android share menu

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, android-intent

I want to add share option in my application from where i can share image to any application(Facebook, twitter, watsapp,Gmail) installed in the mobile. But when i use the following code it only displays the below mentioned apps shown in figure below. How can i add other apps.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("IMAGE/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the text that will be shared.</p>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

[image]

Comment: Are whats app , twitter and facebook installed to your device?

Comment: yes apps are already installed

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the text that will be shared.</p>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Comment: ok thanku it is working ... now it is showing other apps as well but when it click on facebook it opens facebook share page but does not display my sended text ot image.